# template with enumeration need to understand

Tags: c++

This is the first time I am coming across a code such as this. In this code instead of using the keyword `typename` an `enumeration` type is used.
The code looks like this.

```
enum T_Thread
{
    EA,
    EB,
    EC,
    ED
};

Header File
template<T_Thread Thread>   <----Q1- I was expecting template<typename t>...
class SBatch : public ParentClass<Thread>
{
    SBatch(size_t max);
    ....
    ....
};

Cpp File

template<T_Thread Thread>
SBatch<Thread>::SBatch(size_t max) : ParentClass<Thread> <--Q2. Compile Error : expected '(' before ','
{
   ......
   ......
}
```

The parent class looks like this

```
template <T_Thread Thread>
class ParentClass: public MParentClass<Thread>
{
public:
    ParentClass();
....
....
}
```

I have two questions based on this

1. what is the need of having an enum type instead of using `<template typename>`
2. why am I getting a compilation error on

   ```
   SBatch<Thread>::SBatch(size_t max) : ParentClass<Thread>
   ```

I am using MingW gcc 64 bit.

Comment: It's a non-type parameter.

Comment: ...but still compile time, which is the hump most people seemingly find hard to get over when first exposed to them.

Comment: You can read about non-type template parameters at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. what is the need of having an enum type instead of using `<template typename>`

It's just a [non-type parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

> 2. why am I getting a compilation error on
>
>    ```
>    SBatch<Thread>::SBatch(size_t max) : ParentClass<Thread>
>    ```

It's likely you forgot the parentheses.

```
SBatch<Thread>::SBatch(size_t max) : ParentClass<Thread>()
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. what is the need of having an enum type instead of using `<template typename>`

Templates can be parametrised by three kinds of thing:

- Types
- Non-types (which basically means constant values)
- Other templates.

In this case, it's parametrised by a constant value of type `T_Thread`. So `SBatch<EA>` and `SBatch<EB>` are two specialisations of the template, with a different "thread" value for each.

> 2. why am I getting a compilation error

Because the base-class initialiser is wrong; it must supply constructor arguments:

```
SBatch<Thread>::SBatch(size_t max) : ParentClass<Thread>(args)
                                                        ^^^^^^
```

If you want it to be default-initialised, with no constructor arguments, then either give an empty argument list, `()`, or leave the initialiser out altogether.